# Restrict unauthorised access in Component Angular 2

Tags: routes, angular, angular2-routing

I have to prevent user to move on any route until user is logged in.

Can somebody help me how can we achieve this in Angular 2 Component Routing.

Thanks,

Comment: This is far too broad of a question for Stack Overflow and shows no research or effort on your part.  Please clarify your question with what you've tried so far and why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: I mean I am looking for $routeChangeStart in Angular2

Comment: What you're looking for is [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html), see this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112) as well.

Comment: This is plnkr, but this is not runnign code, app-injector.ts has comment.      http://plnkr.co/edit/r2IFYgsFrD526g68nhfg?p=preview

Comment: @AshutoshSingh How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@CanActivate` decorator that angular2 provides. You decorate the component that you want to restrict with a condition. More info can be found in the angular docs:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html#!#lifecycle-hooks

It has an example using a similar decorator called `@CanDeactivate`. This is a good starting point, customize it to your needs.