# Auth0 Lock10 and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I'm integrating the security framework auth0 in my SPA. I followed that tutorial:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs

Everything looks fine and configured. But I didn't find how to secure the states on the ui-router.
In the version 9, was using data: { requiresLogin: true } on the ui-router. I didn't find how to do that in the lock10, and in the tutorial don't have nothing about that.

In the sample on github, they still using the old version lock9. Someone knows how can I force the states to require the login?

Comment: Have you tried using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924577/restrict-unauthorised-access-in-component-angular-2 ?

Comment: Sorry, this is angular1

Answer (score 1):

It appears this functionality has been removed. I went to a non-Auth0-specific way to detect whether a given state requires a user to be logged in, and added the following to my `angular.run(..)`:

```
$rootScope
    .$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (toState.data && toState.data.requiresLogin === true) {
                if (!authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('root.login', { toState: toState, toParams: toParams });
                }
            }
        });
```

My authService is identical to what they prescribe in the Auth0-provided example you linked to, but I also added an `isAuthenticated()` method. Of course, you could inject `$rootScope` into your `angular.run(..)` and check that way too.

Hopefully one of us will learn how to do it within Lock10, but until then this fills the void.

Answer (score 0):

`ui-router` has since [deprecated](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events) `$stateChange*`, so try this:

```
/*jslint latedef:false*/
(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .run(run);

  run.$inject = ['authService', '$transitions'];

  function run(authService, $transitions) {

    $transitions.onStart({
      to: function(state) {
        return state.data && state.data.requiresLogin;
      }
    }, function(trans) {
      if (!authService.isAuthenticated()) {
        authService.login();
        // or if you have a login route:
        // return trans.router.stateService.target('login');
      }
    });
  }

})();
```